# Create variable for insert or change data lake folder path in Databricks

Tags: parameters, directory, path, widget, databricks

Im new with Databricks so thats why i am asking you for any advices.

Current situation:
In DEV environment we used hardcoded folder location of data lake folder in development.
When release this to Acceptance environment we need to manually changes als the hardcoded values in the notebook.

As you can see here we inserted the hardcoded value of the folder.

- storage account name = sadwhpostge001
- container name= excel folder
- name = bronze

In Acceptance environment the **only** difference from the Development is the storage account name.

How can we create parameters and insert the right values when the notebook is deployed in Acceptance? i am thinking using Widget but do not have any best practices.

Any suggestions? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Ideally the mountpoints for different environment should have same name but pointing to different storage account, am assuming the Databricks workspaces are different for each environment -- that way you won't have to change your codes in this case.